# Applying for French citizenship

Tags: france, citizenship

I am trying to find out if it's possible to apply for French/Dual Citizenship. I live in the UK and my mother was born in France. She was evacuated during WWII when she was 9 to London. Her father was Scottish making her half french, she sadly passed away in 1986.  Her mother was French.

Is this enough for me to apply for French Citizenship? I've recently started looking into this and as I thought it's a minefield on the internet. Any advice on where to start would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did your mother retain her French citizenship? Was she a French citizen when you were born?

Comment: Are you interested in *applying* for French citizenship, or in *determining* whether you already are a French citizen?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert on this, but from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law#Through_parentage_.28right_of_blood.29 it seems you can only get citizenship through a parent if you are under 18.